# Is there a way to remove level requirement to Oblivion's quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Aware of the leveling problem of Oblivion, I decided to create my char aiming to be strong while my enemies are weak, by choosing main skills that I would not normally use.
I finished main quest and decided to do all the side quests, and many of them have level requirements.

As I'm low level, it will be hard to grind through high level to do quests like Hermaeus Mora.

Is there a way to remove these quests level requirements?

Comment: Only the Daedric Shrine quests have a level requirement, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make your own mini-mod for this. Since this sounds more like a question for GameDev, where we *develop* stuff in preference of using other people's tools ... let's explain how to go about it the "proper" way first:

1. If not already done so, install [The Elder Scrolls Construction Set](http://cs.elderscrolls.com/constwiki/index.php/TES_Construction_Set) (version 1.2 is fine; you need the older 1.0 only for few specialised tasks which are broken in the latest version). Optionally, install the [Oblivion Script Extender](http://obse.silverlock.org/) and the [Construction Set Extender](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=36370) for significantly easier modding in general.
2. In the TES CS, load the main oblivion.esm by going to the menu item **File -> Data**, marking the tick to the left side of oblivion.esm, and clicking *OK*. The loading will take a while.
3. Open the list of quests by picking the menu item **Character -> Quests...**
4. The quest data window appears, with all the existing quests in the game (even those who aren't "real" quests, or are left-overs from the development) listed.
   [image: Oblivion CS quest window]
5. The next step depends on the quest.

   - Some have the level requirements listed right there, in the "quest conditions" part. In such a case, mark the offending line (it has a [GetLevel](http://cs.elderscrolls.com/constwiki/index.php/GetLevel) check) with the mouse and hit the `[DEL]` key on your keyboard to remove it.
   - Other quests have the level check in the topics which start the quest. You'll have to work through the Topics tab and remove such conditions.
   - Some quests have the level condition (again, using `player.getLevel`) in the quests scripts. Click on the `[...]` button next to the script name to edit those.
   - Finally, both topic and quest stage result scripts can be used for such checks, but I don't believe any vanilla Oblivion quest does so.

For the lazy and in a hurry, there is a mod which does it for you: [No Daedric Quests Level Locks](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=4849).

(**Version** 1.2.0416)

Comment: Wait, when did we become GameDev? o.o

Comment: @mordi2k: You're right. I got it mixed up since the question sounded more like a GameDev one, and I have both sites open anyway. :) Fixed with what I meant in the first place, and added another seldom-used edge case where such a check might hide.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Console Mode. There isn't a way to disable level control, but you could try this:

```
enable the console, by setting bAllowConsole = 1 in the oblivion.ini
enter the console (tilde key)
sq (shows all game quests with ID, find your quest ID)
setstage <questID> 10
```

10 is the enter value for every quest.
Beware to save before EVERY operation, using console can often lead to bugs and inconsistent states.

Everything about Oblivion Console:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a side answer. There are mods that completely get rid of the awkward leveling of oblivion and thus get rid of the level requirements. I really hate the leveling system and for maximum stats you should choose each skill with a different attribute and level carefully or even writing down what you level in a logbook.

One of the best mods IMHO is Oscuro's oblivion overhaul. It gets rid of the leveling and mobs leveling with you. You upgrade skills and attributes automatically by using the skills. The world now has a fixed progression and mobs do not level with you.